# Add spring boot application as dependency to another spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application A which is a spring data service to do some CRUD operations. Now I wanted to add this A as dependency to another Spring boot application B which is just a rest service to access various methods of A. When I did that and started B's Application class, I see the application A getting run and all the configurations are done and stops. What I wanted to achieve is application B should run a tomcat on pot 8080 so that I could access application B's CRUD methods. Could someone please help me to achieve this?

Before writing this question I did search the forum for all relevant threads but could not find a solution.

Comment: Are you using gradle or maven?

Comment: I am using gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a spring boot application A which is a spring data service to
>   do some CRUD operations. Now I wanted to add this A as dependency to
>   another Spring boot application B which is just a rest service to
>   access various methods of A.

According to the described need, I am not sure you need to have two Spring Boot applications.
Having two distinct Spring Boot web based applications assumes that the two applications need to be physically separated. This separation has a cost since you have to make a way to allow the applications to communicate between them : webservice, jms, rmi, jms, etc... and you have to develop and maintain two Spring Boot applications, but you said that

> Spring boot application B which is just a rest service to access
>   various methods of A

If you want to call repository methods of `A` in a straight way from rest services of `B`, why having two distinct applications and make it more complex ? 
A single Spring Boot application with multiple modules could be more suitable and maintainable solution:

```
- parent-my-app (super and parent project)
|
|----> repository-my-app module
|     
|   
|----> rest-my-app module    
                    |----> dependency on repository-my-app module
```

To conclude, strongly decoupling the communication between two layers via two applications has a cost and coping with two Spring Boot application too.
So, if you don't really need it, you should avoid.

Comment: This makes sense to me, based on the project structure you mentioned can you point me to some example how to create this parent and sub modules?

Comment: One more reason why we tried to do this way is that, we wanted the application A be used by many other teams. Not sure if that could be achieved in the way you mentioned.

Comment: This page is excellent to understand how to do it with Gradle : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:structure_of_a_multiproject_build. It explains the base of the multi project with Gradle. Besides, in Gradle folder, look at  the samples/userguide folder, you have multiple examples.

Comment: I am clear now, will try this to setup my application this way.

Comment: I would like to be sure to propose you a relevant solution. Could you detail what you mean by  **"application A be used by many other teams"** ? For example is data should be synchronized between the applications (if an application changes a data, is other applications should be aware of it ?)  Do you need to put data retrieved from repositories in a middle-long term cache (as JPA Level 2 Cache for example) ?